# How to load SVG from a server and insert them inline

Tags: javascript, svg, vue.js

Currently, I am using Webpack's [svg-inline-loader plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/svg-inline-loader) like this [solution](https://gist.github.com/jeremiegirault/fa0a826a2e3a205792e59abfaf377d67) and it works well with static icons.

But now I need to load icons from an HTTP server. And when I try to write the icon's url to a vector's src, it doesn't work. I could just use an `<img>` tag, **but I need to change fill color**.

How do I load icons from the server and insert them as an inline SVG?

Comment: https://codepen.io/eltonmesquita/post/loading-inline-svg

Comment: @StephenThomas you link to exactly what OP is saying doesn't work.

Comment: @EmileBergeron thanks for your edit. Do you know anything that might help me?

Comment: @EmileBergeron They're not at all the same. OP notes that a webpack loader won't work over http. That's absolutely true since webpack happens during the build phase and doesn't involve a network. The codepin post shows how to load SVG assets via AJAX and inject them in the DOM. That's exactly how to achieve what the OP asks.

Comment: @StephenThomas you're right, my bad. I just saw the `<img src="...">` fallback part and thought that it wasn't going to work ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Stephen Thomas shared a valid solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454559/how-to-load-svg-from-a-server-and-insert-them-inline#comment87928270_50454559) with his [link to loading inline svg](https://codepen.io/eltonmesquita/post/loading-inline-svg).

Which would look like the following within Vue.

Say the backend returns the following SVG (notice the `fill="currentColor"`):

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 384 512">
    <path fill="currentColor"
          d="M323.1 441l53.9-53.9c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.5 0-33.9L279.8 256l97.2-97.2c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.5 0-33.9L323.1 71c-9.4-9.4-24.5-9.4-33.9 0L192 168.2 94.8 71c-9.4-9.4-24.5-9.4-33.9 0L7 124.9c-9.4 9.4-9.4 24.5 0 33.9l97.2 97.2L7 353.2c-9.4 9.4-9.4 24.5 0 33.9L60.9 441c9.4 9.4 24.5 9.4 33.9 0l97.2-97.2 97.2 97.2c9.3 9.3 24.5 9.3 33.9 0z"></path>
</svg>
```

You could create a super simple SVG image component:

```
<template>
    <span v-html="content" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        src: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {content: ''};
    },
    watch: {
        src: {
            immediate: true,
            handler(src) {
                axios(src).then((response) => this.content = response.data);
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Then use it whenever you need it:

```
<template>
    <svg-img :src="svgSrc" />
</template>
<script>
import SvgImg from './components/SvgImg.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        SvgImg
    },
    data: {
        svgSrc: 'url/to/backend/times.svg',
    },
}
</script>
```